# Implementing WithFilters in a new trait

Tags: scala, playframework

The Using Filters section of [this article](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaInterceptors) explains how to implement a filter on a Play Framework Global object.

```
object Global extends WithFilter(AccessLog)

object AccessLog extends Filter {
  override def apply(next: RequestHeader => Future[Result])(request: RequestHeader): Future[Result] = {
    val result = next(request)
    play.Logger.info(request + "\n\t => " + result)
    result
  }
}
```

[(see framework source code here - line 93)](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/02e05755753407bc238da6f57f551fa455d820cb/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Filters.scala)

I am creating my own trait that extends GlobalSettings and in the doFilter method I want access to the request parameter that is available to Filter.apply() but GlobalSettings' method is declared like so

```
override def doFilter(next: RequestHeader => Handler): (RequestHeader => Handler) = {
  play.Logger.debug("doFilter:")
  super.doFilter(next)
}
```

How can I get hold of the RequestHeader parameter when overriding the above method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The doFilter method has two parameter sets, the 2nd set consists only of an implicit request so this must be pushed into the overridden method like so...

```
  override def doFilter(next: RequestHeader => Handler): (RequestHeader => Handler) = {
    request => {
      play.Logger.debug("doFilter: " + request)
      super.doFilter(next)(request)
    }
  }
```

Comment: I think it would be moreful for the OP and further visitors, when you add some explaination to your intension.

Comment: In the answer or the question?

Comment: My comment was connected to your answer. And don't forgot to mark your answer as accepted ;-)

Comment: Do you think the explanation I added is now sufficient? PS: Can't accept my own answer for another 13 hours.

Comment: In my eyes yes. You have given a reason, why you went this way. And when you read now your answer, it makes more sens than only some lines of code.